# GIT Commit Message for a PR

Tags: git, github, git-commit, pull-request

Is there any git Command to get the commit message for a specific PR.

`git log` gives me the complete history, but I have a PR and wanted to list all the commit message for the PR.

Answer (score 2):

A PR has nothing to do with `git`, really; that's something that GitHub has created to ease the process of collaborating with others. That means that the `git` command itself doesn't know anything about pull requests.

You have a few options if you want to interact with pull requests on the command line.

GitHub [provides instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally#modifying-an-inactive-pull-request-locally) for checking out a pull request locally.  You can run something like:

```
git fetch origin pull/123/head:my-interesting-pr
```

And then:

```
git checkout my-interesting-pr
```

That's fine for individual PRs, but it doesn't allow you to list existing pull requests, create new ones, or otherwise interact with GitHub pull requests or issues.

---

You can install GitHub's own [gh cli](https://cli.github.com/), which will let you do things like:

```
gh pr list
```

---

There is another CLI for GitHub called [hub](https://hub.github.com/) that when installed properly will let you run:

```
git pr list
```

Both tools will let you check out a pr locally so that you can examine the commits that it includes.

Comment: As I understand it, if you've fetched the github PR refs (with e.g. `git fetch origin refs/pull/234/*:refs/pull/234/*`) you can just e.g. `git log ..refs/pull/234/head`.

Comment: @jthill i did not quite get the suggestion.. are you saying I clone and do git log pull/123/head?

Comment: Use the `git fetch` command line that GitHub describes in their documentation (linked in the above example), and then you can run `git log` on the resulting reference.